# I want only who purchased 2 times or more in Month only that customer name

Tags: mysql, oracle

```
User_ID      Product_id     Date           Quantity
U1            10            16-11-2021       2
U2            20            16-11-2021       1
U3            30            17-11-2021       4
U1            40            18-11-2021       2
U4            10            19-11-2021       1
U2            30            20-11-2021      10
```

Comment: Please demonstrate some effort by including your current query.

Comment: WHERE + GROUP BY + HAVING + COUNT

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? Those are two very different DBMS products

Answer (score 0):

Your table does not have a customer name so the requirement is impossible to achieve.

Assuming that you do have a `customers` table with a `name` column (that you have not mentioned) then you need to:

1. `JOIN` the purchases and `customers` tables together on their primary/foreign key relationship.
2. `GROUP BY` the `Date` column truncated back to the start of the month and the primary key for the customer so you have grouping sets for each customer for each month.
3. Filter the groups to find only those groups `HAVING` a `COUNT` of the number of rows greater than or equal to 2.
4. `SELECT` the customer `name` (either by finding the using an aggregation function like `MAX` within the group or adding the `name` column to the `GROUP BY` clause).